# Can you find and replace fill formatting in word?

Tags: microsoft-word

H, In Microsoft Word, I have a text with fill formatting and want to find and replace it with no formatting. I do not see it as an option the replace format menu.

Comment: Is by "fill formatting" you mean "shading" or "highlighting" ?

Comment: Never mind, I did both.

Answer (score 3):

**Remove Highlighting Method 1: Choose No Color**

- Select the highlighted texts
- In Home tab, Font group, click "Text Highlight Color"
- In the drop-down menu, choose "No Color".

**Remove Highlighting Method 2: Use "Find and Replace"**

1. Click Home then Replace
2. In the Find and Replace dialog, select the Replace tab
3. Click in "Find what"
4. Click "More"
5. Click "Format"
6. Click "Highlight"
7. Click in "Replace with"
8. Repeat steps 5 and 6 twice
9. Click "Replace All".

**Remove Shading Method: Choose No Color**

- Select the text
- In Home tab, Paragraph group, click "Shading"
- Select "No Color".

**Remove Both Highlighting and Shading : VBA**

- Select the text or the entire document
- Press Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor
- Click menu *Insert > Module*
- Paste inside the module the following lines:

  ```
  Sub RemoveShadingandHighlights()
    Selection.Font.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
    Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
    Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
  End Sub
  ```
- Click "Run" to remove both highlighting and shading.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[5 Methods to Remove Highlighting or Shading in Your Word Document](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/5-methods-remove-highlighting-shading-word-document/).

Comment: VBA: Before pasting, you need to have place to paste it; so "Add a Module", click in the source text window/pane. A beginner would get "nuts" over that missing step.

Comment: @Hannu: Right - missing step added.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find and replace fill formatting in Microsoft Word. To do this, you can use the Find and Replace objects. First, use the Find object to search for the specific fill formatting you want to replace. Then, use the Replacement property to replace the fill formatting with no formatting. You can access the Find object from either the Selection object or the Range object.

Here's an example of how to replace fill formatting with no formatting using the Find and Replace objects:

1. Press Ctrl + H to open the Find and Replace dialog box.
2. In the "Find what" field, enter the fill formatting you want to replace.
3. In the "Replace with" field, leave it blank to replace the fill formatting with no formatting.
4. Click on the "Format" button at the bottom of the dialog box and select "Highlight" to specify the fill formatting you want to replace.
5. Click on the "No Formatting" button to specify that you want to replace the fill formatting with no formatting.
6. Click on the "Replace All" button to replace all instances of the fill formatting with no formatting.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid these are grey-shaded form fields and you cannot remove shade from them within the Word. A workaround is to save the file as a PDF and then convert the PDF back to Word. Be warned you may lose all the formatting.
Regards,
Mahmood